# Perl email changing from option

Tags: perl, email

I am using perl to generate mail from server for any network events.

Part of that code is:

```
use Mail::Send;
$email->set('From', 'Mahesh Gohil');
```

and based on this code it generates e-mail like below:

```
Mahesh.Gohil@nsetools.controlnet.equant.net
```

Here it is adding '.' dot between my first and last name.

I want from address something like

```
Mahesh Gohil@nsetools.controlnet.equant.net
      ^- There is space between first and last name.
```

Comment: You want it to generate an invalid email address? Why?

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a mail address containing white space characters ([RFC2821 and RFC2822](http://www.remote.org/jochen/mail/info/chars.html)).

I think that the from address that you see is the address of the sender, and have nothing to do with the property that you set ...

Comment: But i see message containing from address like 'Peter Tom eTEC Paris [paubry@nsetools.controlnet.equant.net]'...How is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Email addresses themselves cannot contain a white space.

However, the interpretation of the email address is up to the SMTP server you use, and that can vary from system to system. According to [RCF2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) Section 3.4, you can try something like this:

```
First Last <email@address.com>
```

as an email address. And, your SMTP should understand that. However, you might not be able to do that with `Mail::Send`. Try with [Net::SMTP](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/SMTP.html). This module comes with the standard Perl distribution and talks directly to the SMTP server. You have to understand mail headers a bit better with `Net::SMTP` than with `Mail::Send`, but it should work if `Mail::Send` doesn't.